# Why does statsmodels return four entries for confidence interval instead of two?

Tags: plot, linear-regression, statsmodels, confidence-interval

I have problems to interpret what [conf_int()](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.PredictionResults.conf_int.html) actually does and how to visualize it properly.

I would expect an array of two values for the upper and lower limit of the confidence interval. But I get a 2x2 array, probably due to my input but why? Also, I do not understand how to plot this properly as shown by two example datasets. Why are there negative values for this datasets? This does not seem right.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def get_LR(x,y):
    X=x
    x = x.reshape(-1,1)
    alpha = 0.05 # 95% confidence interval
    
    #get linear regression
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(x,y)
    
    #get confidence intervall
    res = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(x)).fit()
    conf_interval = res._results.conf_int(alpha=0.05,cols=None)
    print(conf_interval)
    
    #plot
    plt.plot(x,y,"ok")
    plt.plot(x, model.predict(x),"k")
    plt.fill_between(X,model.predict(x)-conf_interval[1,0],model.predict(x)+conf_interval[1,1],color="k",alpha=0.1)

x = np.array([2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019])
y1 = np.array([2.83222595, 2.92614066, 2.71348665, 2.85999196, 3.0524628,  3.08661191, 3.23925397, 3.35145337])
y2 = np.array([0.70622701, 0.79255862, 0.9382424,  0.7389387,  0.79157435, 0.63576309, 0.49290489, 0.58930566])

get_LR(x,y1)
get_LR(x,y2)
```

My code results in the following:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4oUC.png)

Comment: `results.conf_int` contains the confidence interval for the parameters not for a prediction.  For those you need to call `results.get_prediction()`